# Need an elegant way to move siblings into a hierarchical structure based on attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I need an elegant way to group siblings as children based on attribute values.  This would be similar to transforming an html table into hierarchal data based on the ‘colspan’ attribute.

The input structure has multiple sibling nodes with child nodes containing data.  However, the data node may contain a level attribute indicating hierarchical superiority.

**INPUT**

```
<root>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="4">ABC</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="3">fff</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data>8000</Data>
    <Data>01/04/2013</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="3">ggg</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data>2000</Data>
    <Data>01/05/2013</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="4">DEF</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="3">iii</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data>2000</Data>
    <Data>01/22/2013</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="4">GHI</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="3">mmm</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data>4000</Data>
    <Data>07/05/2011</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data level="3">nnn</Data>
  </Sibling>
  <Sibling>
    <Data>6000</Data>
    <Data>01/07/2011</Data>
  </Sibling>
</root>
```

Using the level attribute I need to move siblings to become children as shown below.

**OUTPUT**

```
<Main>
  <Group>
    <Data level="4">ABC</Data>
    <Subgroup>
      <Data level="3">fff</Data>
      <Child>
        <Data>8000</Data>
        <Data>01/04/2013</Data>
      </Child>
    </Subgroup>
    <Subgroup>
      <Data level="3">ggg</Data>
      <Child>
        <Data>2000</Data>
        <Data>01/05/2013</Data>
      </Child>
    </Subgroup>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <Data level="4">DEF</Data>
    <Subgroup>
      <Data level="3">iii</Data>
      <Child>
        <Data>2000</Data>
        <Data>01/22/2013</Data>
      </Child>
    </Subgroup>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <Data level="4">GHI</Data>
    <Subgroup>
      <Data level="3">mmm</Data>
      <Child>
        <Data>4000</Data>
        <Data>07/05/2011</Data>
      </Child>
    </Subgroup>
    <Subgroup>
      <Data level="3">nnn</Data>
      <Child>
        <Data>6000</Data>
        <Data>01/07/2011</Data>
      </Child>
    </Subgroup>
  </Group>
</Main>
```

The style sheet I’ve developed isn’t very elegant and makes assumptions about the level value.  It creates parent nodes by outputting open and closed tags based on logic and level values.  I’d prefer passing nodes and adding children but can’t find an example of this being done.  Does anyone have a more elegant way to do this?

**STYLESHEET**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="group_begin">&lt;Group&gt;</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="subgroup_begin">&lt;Subgroup&gt;</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="group_end">&lt;/Group&gt;</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="subgroup_end">&lt;/Subgroup&gt;</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Main>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
    </Main>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="Sibling">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Data[not(@level)]">
          <xsl:call-template name="Sibling">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="next_level" select="following-sibling::*[1]/Data/@level"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="Sibling">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="Data/@level"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="next_level" select="0"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$group_end"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Sibling">
    <xsl:param name="level"  />
    <xsl:param name="next_level"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$level = '4'">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$group_begin"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$level = '3'">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$subgroup_begin"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <Child>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </Child>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$subgroup_end"/>
        <xsl:if test="$next_level = 4">
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$group_end"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I’ve looked into using the technique here [wrap sibling nodes based on on attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854811/wrap-sibling-nodes-based-on-on-attribute) but the attribute level is really a relative value and not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar problem solved using XSLT 2.0 here: http://www.saxonica.com/papers/ideadb-1.1/mhk-paper.xml

Do you absolutely need this to be XSLT 1.0? That's more difficult, but no means impossible. You basically need to master the technique of "sibling recursion" where the template rule for a particular node does apply-templates on its immediately following sibling. Searching for "sibling recursion" might generate some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Unfortunately I'm stuck with 1.0 until python's lxml can support XSLT 2.0. I'm using "following-sibling" now, but can't quite get the proper nesting correctly.

Comment: Yes, sibling recursion can be tricky even when you're used to it. When you get it right the code is beautifully simple and clear, but getting there can be tough.